# Failing to load twitter Bootstrap resource when using angular-cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have used Angular CLI to build my first Angular2 application.  I'm trying to make use of the twitter Bootstrap modules but it's failing to find it:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

I have an index.html with the following line in the

```
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also then have the single line in the ./public/site.css:

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

The Bootstrap module exists here ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/.. but it still can't find it.  Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `angular-cli-builds.js`, you need to add the file so it's copied during build.

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  ...
  'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
]
```

It will then be available in browser in vendor folder, so change `site.css` to

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

If it doesn't work, after build, check your `dist/` folder manually, locate the file and update the paths...

More info here: [3rd party lib installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs)

Comment: brilliant - that worked!  thank you, you won't believe how much toying around i did until I gave up and posted.  thanks.